# Python connection refused on first try using import requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I tried this simples code on a Debian 10:

```
import requests

asn_url = f'https://bgp.he.net/country/BR'
req = requests.get(asn_url)
```

when I run, I get the follow error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 841, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 301, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f74e5374fd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='bgp.he.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /country/BR (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f74e5374fd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sock.py", line 14, in <module>
    req = requests.get(asn_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='bgp.he.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /country/BR (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f74e5374fd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'))
```

I know it seems it is refusing the connection, but why?
It is the same error since the first try

I used this on an ubuntu desktop server and it worked well, but after try on Debian 10 it didn't work.

Comment: I would be curious to try to curl the address or ping the address's ip from the debian...and see if its just a python problem or a problem connecting from the debian box.

Comment: did you try this url in web browser on Debian 10 ? You may also check `ping 8.8.8.8` to see if you get answer from Google DNS (`8.8.8.8`) Maybe your Debian is not connected to internet.